# Hadoop - MapReduce not reducing

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to reduce a map like this:

```
01 true
01 true
01 false
02 false
02 false
```

where the first column is of Text, the second is BooleanWritable. The aim is to keep only those keys which only contain `false` next to them, and then write pairs of the first columns digits (so the output for above input would be `0, 2`). For this, I wrote the following reducer:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.BooleanWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class BeadReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text _key, Iterable<BooleanWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // process values
        boolean dontwrite= false;
        for (BooleanWritable val : values) {
            dontwrite = (dontwrite || val.get());
        }
        if (!dontwrite) {
            context.write(new Text(_key.toString().substring(0,1)), new Text(_key.toString().substring(1,2)));
        }
        else {
            context.write(new Text("not"), new Text("good"));
        }

    }

}
```

This, however, does nothing. Nor does it write the pairs, not `"not good"`, as if it doesn't even enter the if-else branch. All I get is the mapped (mapping works as intended) values.

The driver:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.BooleanWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class BeadDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "task2");
        job.setJarByClass(hu.pack.task2.BeadDriver.class);
        // TODO: specify a mapper
        job.setMapperClass(hu.pack.task2.BeadMapper.class);
        // TODO: specify a reducer
        job.setReducerClass(hu.pack.task2.BeadReducer.class);

        // TODO: specify output types
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(BooleanWritable.class);

        // TODO: specify input and output DIRECTORIES (not files)
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("local"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("outfiles"));

        FileSystem fs;
        try {
            fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            if (fs.exists(new Path("outfiles")))
                fs.delete(new Path("outfiles"),true);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!job.waitForCompletion(true))
            return;
    }

}
```

The mapper:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.BooleanWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class BeadMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, BooleanWritable > {
    private final Text wordKey = new Text("");

    public void map(LongWritable ikey, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] friend = value.toString().split(";");
        String[] friendswith = friend[1].split(",");
        for (String s : friendswith) {
            wordKey.set(friend[0] + s);
            context.write(wordKey, new BooleanWritable(true));
            wordKey.set(s + friend[0]);
            context.write(wordKey, new BooleanWritable(true));
        }
        if (friendswith.length > 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < friendswith.length-1; ++i) {
                for(int j = i+1; j < friendswith.length; ++j) {
                    wordKey.set(friendswith[i] + friendswith[j]);
                    context.write(wordKey, new BooleanWritable(false));
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I wonder what the problem is, what am I missing?

Comment: Show us the code for mapper. Also, the reducer says that its input value is of type Text but your reduce method is Iterable<BooleanWritable>.

Comment: Added mapper via edit!
So it should be `public class BeadReducer extends Reducer<Text, BooleanWritable, Text, Text> ` ?

Comment: It should be `Reducer<Text, BooleanWritable, Text, BooleanWritable>` because you declared the output key class as `Text` and value class as `BooleanWritable`

Comment: I changed it to `public class BeadReducer extends Reducer<Text, BooleanWritable, Text, Text>` and it's now working. Please add as answer, and then I can choose your solution! Also one more question: setOutputKeyClass: does this specify the output of the mapper, or the reducer, or both? If both, can I change the output of the mapper to be different than the output of the reducer? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output key and value types of a mapper should be input types for reducer and therefore in your case, the reducer must inherit from

```
Reducer<Text, BooleanWritable, Text, BooleanWritable>
```

The `setOutputKeyClass` and `setOutputValueClass` set the types for the job output i.e. both map and reduce. If you want to specify a different type for mapper, you should use the methods `setMapOutputKeyClass` and `setMapOutputValueClass`.

As a side note, when you don't want the true values in the output then why emit them from the mapper. Also with the below code in reducer,

```
for (BooleanWritable val : values) {
    dontwrite = (dontwrite || val.get());
}
```

if `dontwrite` becomes `true` once it will be true till the end of the loop. You may want to change your logic for optimization.

Comment: Valid point! Thank you. Might breaking the for loop upon `dontwrite` becoming `true` improve speed?

Comment: It depends on the size of the values. If it is huge, breaking the loop early  helps reduce the runtime for reducer.